# Can't execute Scheduler without setting Duration time

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I download JMeter 4 which changed Scheduler,

I failed to execute with startup delay without Duration:

1. Check Scheduler in Thread Group
2. Enter Startup delay (in seconds) as 1
3. Keep Duration field empty

Error instead of executing successfully with startup delay

[image]

There's no error (or any record) in log although pop up refer to log.

Startup isn't mandatory, but Duration is mandatory, it should state it or allow it to be empty if it shouldn't be mandatory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed an enhancement that should improve UX.

Feel free to open enhancement request at:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html